# Rails 3, add id param to cookie array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have the following code...

view

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
   ...
    <td><%= link_to "Add to Cart", add_to_cart_product_path(product), :method => :put %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
def add_to_cart
    if cookies[:products].blank?
      cookies[:products] = params[:id]
    else
      cookies[:products] = cookies[:products] << params[:id]
    end
    redirect_to products_url
  end
end
```

I'm trying to build a super simple simulation of a shopping cart. I have products, and I want to add the product_id to my products cookie if the user clicks 'add to cart'. The issue I'm having is I only get a single id in the cookie at a time. In fact the cookie on seems to get written to the first time I click 'add to cart' for a product. After that, nothing is written.

Comment: You're actually doing it wrong, create an `order_id` in session and then create an Order object and associate products as line_items(a separate table) to it. And then later, look for `session[:order_id]` and find `current_order` instead of looking for cookies of product ids.

Comment: That is because you are using same hash key products every time. Use unique keys in your hash i.e product_id

Comment: This is for demonstration purposes, that is why I am using cookies rather than session. I want to actually see the values in the cookie.

Comment: @zaingz not following you. params[:id] is unique.

Comment: @Lumbee I am talking about keys in cookies hash. You are always saving values under same key, that is products( cookies[:products] )

Comment: @zaingz Do I have to use key/values? I just want an array of id's like cookies[:products] = [1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked...

```
 def add_to_cart
    @products = cookies[:products]
    if @products.blank?
      @products = cookies[:products] = params[:id]
    else
      cookies[:products] = @products + ',' + params[:id]
    end
    redirect_to products_url
  end
end
```

Looks like I needed to assign the cookie to a variable before doing anything with it.